# Lenovo IBM ThinkPad T40 - Wireless issue - not connecting to internet

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, thinkpad

This machine is running on windows xp pro. LAN connection works perfect, wireless not so well. It see's all the signals in the building and I am 150% certain the router/wireless signals are perfect.

I have two signals at my work, a "N" and a "G" frequency. When I connect to the N, it gets to the point were it tries to validate and it keeps trying to do that.

The windows error message when trying for the "N" signal is this:

- "Windows was unable to find a certificate to log you on to the network xswn".

The "G" signal gives a message almost immediately after trying to connect to it saying:

- "Windows is unable to connect to the selected network. The network may no longer be in range. Please refresh the list of available networks, and try to connect again."

The G router is literally 5 feet from me and is showing full strength before and after a refresh. Device manager shows everything is well.

What I've tried to do to fix it:

- Virus clean up
- Registry fix
- Windows repair
- System restore
- "Combofix"/"rougefix"
- "Winsockxpfix" (windows xp socket fix)
- Uninstall then reinstall of driver

Nothing has worked so far. My assumption is the wireless card has gone bad or something. 
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should check and clean your machine for dust. If a lot has accumulated, it can damage or cause the devices within to malfunction, or not function at all.